# Android: making a service (beginner)

Tags: android, service

I'm kind'a new to java/android (old C#-coder). 
I've created some logic and it does work on an activity.

Now I'd like to perform that function each 5 minutes as a service.

Is there a good tutorial out there which is showing how to create an android service which does run a function every x minutes?

Thanks a lot

James

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

It explains the different types of Android services and then walks you through creating a service that loops and runs something every five seconds.